# Criteria used to create and select leaf nodes in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn

I just want to know the details of what (and how) is the criteria used by `sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier` to create leaf nodes. I know that the parameters `criterion{“gini”, “entropy”}, default=”gini”` and `splitter{“best”, “random”}, default=”best”` are used to split nodes. However, I could not find more information about the threshold used for spliting.

There are some methods involved in the creation of leaf nodes: post-pruning (cutting back the tree after a tree has been built) and pre-pruning (preventing overfitting by trying and stopping the tree-building process early).  It would be very useful to know more details about the criteria used for splitting to have a better understanding and be able to customize these models even more.

Comment: Related: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/77108/64377

Answer (score 0):

Pre-pruning is handled by a variety of parameters:
`max_depth`, `min_samples_split`, `min_samples_leaf`, `min_weight_fraction_leaf`, `max_leaf_nodes`, and `min_impurity_decrease`.

[Post-pruning is relatively new to sklearn](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/67389/55122), and is accomplished with minimal cost-complexity pruning, parameter `ccp_alpha`.